CSS style not applied to body tag in React project
I'm having a problem with a style defined in a CSS file, that is not correctly recognized.
It seems that what I define in the CSS file is totally ignored.
My idea is to manage dark mode by dynamically adding class="dark" to the body tag. To do it, I'm using document.body.classList.add('dark') and, by inspecting the code, I can see that the class is correctly added to the body tag when a button is clicked.
Then I have a CSS file with the following code:
body {
  --color-background: #fafafa;
  --color-foreground: #8a2be2;
  --icon-color: #1f2023;
  --secondary-copy: #1f2023;
}

body.dark {
  --color-background: #1f2023;
  --color-foreground: #8a2be2;
  --icon-color: #fafafa;
  --secondary-copy: #fafafa;
}

These variables are use inside several components in the project.
So, what I expected is that when the class is not added, the body style is taken, while when the class is added, body.dark style is used, but it is not working.
By inspecting the code I notice that body.dark style is not present in the stylesheet, even if it is in the file, while body is present.
I add an image, I hope it can help to understand the problem.
image
Thank you for your help.

without further info, there is no way to find out what the issue is. can you please send a minimal reproducible example? also, just a tip from experience, check if you have any other objects with the class name "dark" and check if you can hot-reload css

hello, i tried reproducing your case and it works well for me https://codepen.io/artikandri/pen/XWwMNgp , did you check if there is some other code that might have conflicted with this?

Maybe you can also include some info about your compiler or something :) this might be a case of wrong css/scss/sass compiler output

Hi guys, thank you for your help. Your answers made me think that the problem could be a conflict, so I checked and it was like that. I solved now, thank you again

from my practice you cannot play like that in CSS.. one of the way is to declare CSS variable inside :root, like that:
:root {
  --light-color-background: #fafafa;
  --light-color-foreground: #8a2be2;
  --light-icon-color: #1f2023;
  --light-secondary-copy: #1f2023;
  --dark-color-background: #1f2023;
  --dark-color-foreground: #8a2be2;
  --dark-icon-color: #fafafa;
  --dark-secondary-copy: #fafafa;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--light-color-background);
  color:  var(--light-secondary-copy);
}

body.dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-color-background);
  color:  var(--dark-secondary-copy);
}

and then switch the theme.. by using classList you can use toggle method:
const onButtonClick = () =>  { 
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark")
}

here you can see working example: https://codepen.io/mario-boss/pen/bGyqqZQ
